# github action outputting a string, passing string with quotes to next job

Tags: github-actions

I have a github action output that will ultimately be used for a terraform plan. the variable for that plan is a list(string). The sting is generated from an output on a python script. This script puts the sting inside of a bracket (["10.0.0.1/24"]). The problem I'm running into is when output runs and sends to the next job the quotes are pulled off and the input list(string) once imported to the next job looks like the following.

[10.0.0.1/24]

the terraform plan that needs this then gets stuck on the plan portion specifically when it imports the list(string).

Im suspecting the problem is how this variable is being sent from job a to job b. I validated that suspicion by running the terraform plan with a static input of ["10.0.0.1/24"] sure enough it worked and finished the plan.

The Code

```
  createVNET:
    uses: redacted/gitops-tf-azure-vnet/.github/workflows/plan.yml@main
    with:
      ref: "main"
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: "redacted"
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID: "redacted"
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: "redacted"
      state_resource_group: "redacted"
      state_storageaccount: "redacted"
      state_container: "redacted"
      tgtresourceGroup: "redacted"
      tgtvnetName: "redacted"
      tgtLocation: "redacted"
      tgtAddress: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.vnet}}
      tgtSubnet: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.subnet}}
      subnetName: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.name}}
   secrets: inherit
   needs: output_stuff
  reserveSubnet: #this is the python script that spits out the network 
    uses: redacted/ipFinder/.github/workflows/apply.yml@main
    with:
      ref: "main"
      az_sub : "TEST" #Either TEST or PROD
      app_size : "S"
      app_deployment: "AZ"
      app_name: "TestAPP1"
      state_container: "redacted"
      vnet : "redacted"
    secrets: inherit
  output_stuff:
    runs-on:
      labels: ephemeral
    outputs:
      subnet: ${{ steps.subnets.outputs.subnet }}
      name: ${{ steps.names.outputs.name }}
      vnet: ${{ steps.vnets.outputs.vnet }}
    steps:
    - name: Output Chosen Subnet
      id: subnets
      run: |
        echo subnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.cidr}} >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Output Chosen Appname
      id: names
      run: |
        echo name=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.appName}} >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    - name: Output Chosen vnet
      id: vnets
      run: |
        echo vnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.vnet}} >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    needs: reserveSubnet
```

tgtAddress and tgtSubnet both require a list(string) per the terraform plan. just to restate the problem the output being sent from output_stuff removes the quotes when it's ingested in the job createVnet. When we are on the job of output_stuff the echo does show the quotes properly. Is this by design? if it's by design can I outport to json or something then reappend them as an intermediary step?

The python Output for those wanting to see this.

```
def createNetwork(next_available_net,appName,username,password,vnet):#create Network inside  reference container and assign a comment which is the app name 
connection = default_redacted_connection(username,password)
for x in next_available_net['networks']:
    network = objects.Network.create(connection, cidr=x, comment=appName)
    cidr = x 
output_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_OUTPUT')
cidr=f'["{cidr}"]'
vnet=f'["{vnet}"]'
```

for those wondering I am appending [""] to the variable in the hopes that it would be treated as a string and any changes from github would be ignored. That's not working so it can be ignored.

## return Chosen Subnet

```
with open(output_file, "a") as github_output:
    github_output.write(f"cidr={cidr}\n")
    github_output.write(f"name={appName}\n")
    github_output.write(f"vnet={vnet}\n")
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the content of `vnet` is the string `["10.0.0.1/24"]` and you do this:

```bash
echo vnet=${{needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.vnet}} >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

you drop the double quotes. The command first gets the expansion of the `needs` context interpolated, so it's equivalent to this:

```bash
echo vnet=["10.0.0.1/24"] >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

You can test what this does in an interactive shell:

```bash
$ echo ["10.0.0.1/24"]
[10.0.0.1/24]
```

The quotes get removed, because they're syntactical, and not literal.

The best way to fix that is to set the context expansion as an environment value, and then use an environment variable:

```yaml
    - name: Output Chosen vnet
      id: vnets
      env:
        vnet: ${{ needs.reserveSubnet.outputs.vnet }}
      run: |
        echo "vnet=$vnet" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

I've also quoted `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`, which isn't necessary, but good practice.

Doing this also prevents [script injections](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

Comment: That did it that’s for the help and explanation.